# I am trying to call a function inside of an if statement but it's not working. I am also using turtle in the function

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

So I am making a sunglasses shop.
This is my code:

```
# Sun_Glasses_Shop             

import turtle
import random
from random import randint

def build_glasses() :
    crim = turtle.Turtle()
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'plum', 'sienna']

crim.color(random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors))
randpos = randint(-100, 100)
crim.width(2)

crim.penup()
crim.setposition(randpos, randpos)
crim.pendown()

# Making First Box 

crim.begin_fill()
for x in range(4):
    crim.forward(50)
    crim.right(90)

crim.end_fill()
crim.forward(50)
crim.right(90)
crim.forward(5)
crim.left(90)
crim.forward(50)
crim.left(90)
crim.forward(5)
crim.right(90)
crim.begin_fill()

# Making Second Box 

for x in range(4):
    crim.forward(50)
    crim.right(90)
crim.end_fill()

print("Welcome to the glasses shop, would you like some?")
A1 = str(input())
if A1 == "yes" or A1 == "Yes" :
    A1 = str(input())    print("Okay, coming right up!")
    build_glasses()
else :
    print("I dont understand try asking me later, bye!")
```

But when I run the code it prints out this in the module:

```
Welcome to the glasses shop, would you like some?
yes

Okay, coming right up!
```

The turtle graphics don't pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code (you have an indentation error):

```
import turtle
import random
from random import randint

def build_glasses() :
    crim = turtle.Turtle()
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'plum', 'sienna']

    crim.color(random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors))
    randpos = randint(-100, 100)
    crim.width(2)

    crim.penup()
    crim.setposition(randpos, randpos)
    crim.pendown()

    # Making First Box 

    crim.begin_fill()
    for x in range(4):
        crim.forward(50)
        crim.right(90)

    crim.end_fill()
    crim.forward(50)
    crim.right(90)
    crim.forward(5)
    crim.left(90)
    crim.forward(50)
    crim.left(90)
    crim.forward(5)
    crim.right(90)
    crim.begin_fill()

    # Making Second Box 

    for x in range(4):
        crim.forward(50)
        crim.right(90)
    crim.end_fill()

print("Welcome to the glasses shop, would you like some?")
A1 = str(input())
if A1 == "yes" or A1 == "Yes" :
    print("Okay, coming right up!")
    build_glasses()
else :
    print("I dont understand try asking me later, bye!")
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the glasses shop, would you like some?
yes
Okay, coming right up!
>>>
```

[image: Output]